# How can I enable audio on a raspberry pi 4 running ubuntu 19?

Tags: audio, ubuntu

I cant get audio on my raspberry pi 4 running ubuntu 19.Does anyone have a solution.Also I am running the 32 bit version. I cant get audio even though I have a headphone plugged in.

Comment: What audio system do you use? ALSA, Jack, PulseAudio, etc.

Comment: I voted to close this question because the OP failed to provide more info about their setup **for more than two years**, and guessing what could have been wrong with an old Ubuntu is simply not productive.

Answer (score 1):

Use this command

```
 amixer cset numid=3 1
```

This will fix the problem. If it doesn't work then try it with `sudo`